# How to access existing reCAPTCHA v2 settings

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, react-google-recaptcha

I have a site and secret key that I created in 2020. I am attempting to access the reCAPTCHA admin console to change some settings on the existing keys. Whenever I go to the following URL: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin, I am immediatly redirected to: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create. How do I access an existing reCAPTCHA configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I think this admin console moves around very regularly and the documentation doesn't link to it. I was able to access it here: https://console.cloud.google.com/security/recaptcha

Depending on when you created the key initially, you may have to choose between "classic" and "enterprise" keys. But they started actively pushing you towards enterprise keys and for some reason the old links don't show all the keys you may be administrator on: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and I thought I was going crazy . Turns out I was logged in the wrong google account that didn't have the admin rights.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So, I should check I am logged into the correct account and that I also have admin rights? We were going down the path of upgrading to v3...but if this idea works maybe we don't need to do that?